# Exclude number range in Google Search

Tags: google-search

I would like to exclude search results containing numbers in a specific range. My best search term so far was:

```
foo -1950..2009
```

Google, however seems to ignore the minus sign and return results with numbers exactly in this range. How can this be done? I have experimented with advanced search, though without success.

The following will not solve the problem:

```
foo 2010..2012
```

The reason for this is that the pages that I search for will contain these numbers (for example in date stamps on the page).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an [example search](https://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=13&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=-1950+-1951+-1952+-1953+-1954+-1955+-1956+-1957+-1958+-1959+-1960+-1961+-1962+-1963+-1964+-1965+-1966+-1967+-1968+-1969+-1970+-1971+-1972+-1973+-1974+-1975+-1976+-1977+-1978+-1979+-1980+-1981+-1982+-1983+-1984+-1985+-1986+-1987+-1988+-1989+-1990+-1991+-1992+-1993+-1994+-1995+-1996+-1997+-1998+-1999+-2000+-2001+-2002+-2003+-2004+-2005+-2006+-2007+-2008+-2009#hl=en&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=foo+-1950+-1951+-1952+-1953+-1954+-1955+-1956+-1957+-1958+-1959+-1960+-1961+-1962+-1963+-1964+-1965+-1966+-1967+-1968+-1969+-1970+-1971+-1972+-1973+-1974+-1975+-1976+-1977+-1978+-1979+-1980+-1981+-1982+-1983+-1984+-1985+-1986+-1987+-1988+-1989+-1990+-1991+-1992+-1993+-1994+-1995+-1996+-1997+-1998+-1999+-2000+-2001+-2002+-2003+-2004+-2005+-2006+-2007+-2008+-2009&oq=foo+-1950+-1951+-1952+-1953+-1954+-1955+-1956+-1957+-1958+-1959+-1960+-1961+-1962+-1963+-1964+-1965+-1966+-1967+-1968+-1969+-1970+-1971+-1972+-1973+-1974+-1975+-1976+-1977+-1978+-1979+-1980+-1981+-1982+-1983+-1984+-1985+-1986+-1987+-1988+-1989+-1990+-1991+-1992+-1993+-1994+-1995+-1996+-1997+-1998+-1999+-2000+-2001+-2002+-2003+-2004+-2005+-2006+-2007+-2008+-2009&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=serp.3...6418.6805.0.6927.4.4.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.4.4X7yIiqyTPE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=2db105060e3663e9&biw=1619&bih=946):

```
foo -1950 -1951 -1952 -1953 -1954 -1955 -1956 -1957 -1958 -1959 -1960 -1961 -1962 -1963 -1964 -1965 -1966 -1967 -1968 -1969 -1970 -1971 -1972 -1973 -1974 -1975 -1976 -1977 -1978 -1979 -1980 -1981 -1982 -1983 -1984 -1985 -1986 -1987 -1988 -1989 -1990 -1991 -1992 -1993 -1994 -1995 -1996 -1997 -1998 -1999 -2000 -2001 -2002 -2003 -2004 -2005 -2006 -2007 -2008 -2009
```

Currently, the `before:` and `after:` operators in Gmail do not work in Google Searches.  There is no practical way to negate the range at the moment.

Comment: This is the best solution so far, even though I get the following message when I run the query: ""1981" (and any subsequent words) was ignored because we limit queries to 32 words".

Answer (score 2):

The `-` operator works only on the following word or phrase. Put a minus sign just before words that you don't want e.g. `-rodent`, `-"Jack Russell"`. Google search doesn't have the option to ignore a range of value with the `-` characters.

I think the best you could do is specify ranges except the range you don't want. E.g. - if you wanted to skip the range 1906 to 1999, you could do -

```
foobar 1900..1905 2000..2005
```

It's not perfect, but the only method you can follow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I mentioned, your suggested method does not work at all. I wonder if there are other search engines that offer such functionality.

Comment: TBH, you could achieve it with Google if you could add all the numbers you want to avoid one by one. Like `foo -1950 -1951 -1952` and so on. I didn't mention it because that's not a feasible solution.